# can't comeback on lock screen after closing laptop

Tags: 18.04, dell, xps

I just bought a dell xps 9570, removed windows and installed ubuntu 18.04.

Everything seems to work fine but when i close the laptop's lid i can't comeback on the lock screen (the screen remains black). After a few seconds the fan starts making a lot of noise. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your kernel and make sure nouveau is disabled. Check out my post here https://medium.com/@pwaterz/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-the-15-inch-dell-xps-9570-with-nvidia-1050ti-gpu-4b9a2901493d. I documented the steps for doing both of those.